# WHMCS pages redirect to clientarea.php if user not logged in

Tags: php, whmcs

WHMCS pages (for example cart.php) redirects to clientarea.php when user is not logged in.
I need to disable this and show cart.php page even if user doesn't logged in.

I have unchecked this :

> Tick this box to skip the homepage and forward users directly to the client area/login form upon first visiting WHMCS

From:

```
WHMCS Admin > Setup > General Settings > Other
```

But doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

It is strange behavior indeed. The option you mentioned only redirect index.php to clientarea.php, but not all pages.

- First, clear template cache: Utilities > System > Clean Up > Empty
  Template Cache.
- Open whmcs in a new private browser window, just to make
  sure that no cookies are affecting the default behavior.
- If you're using customized template, try to use the default one that
  comes with WHMCS.
- If you added any addons/modules, go disable them.
- Also, check your includes/hooks folder, as some hooks may added some
  functions that caused your issue.